# ng build is taking too much time on every single change

Tags: angular, webpack, ng-build

is it possible to disable webpack chunk optimization  or sealing in ng build application in development environment . I am facing an issue is that whenever i made a single change in my angular (ts, html, css....), the rebuild is happening very slow. 
suggest me to improve it.

Comment: It's already disabled by default.

Answer (score 4):

`ng build` is the build you use for a production environment. This build has optimizations of code enabled and disabling those wouldn't make any sense in 99% of time.

Instead, do it like the other developers and use

```
ng serve
```

which even has a watcher and development server ready to use. Also, it doesn't optimize the code for production builds as `ng build` would do, since is faster.